# C# Perform drag drop between datagridrow to treenode and vice versa

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview, drag-and-drop

I have datatree (kind of folder tree) that each folder represend as node. Next to it, I have datagridview that each row in it represent the treenode content.

What I need is to drag and drop node from the treeview to the datagridview and vice versa.

Does anyone have an idea or reference of how to do it?